# Replace array elements with object properties

Tags: javascript

My object

```
var person = [{ FIrstName: "", LastName: "", MiddleName: "" }];
```

My data

```
var names = [
    "Steve", "Mark", "John",     // person 1
    "James", "Andrew", "wells",  // person 2
    "Clarke", "Finche", "Gomes"  // person 3
];
```

So I want to push the names array in person object.

```
$(names).each(function (index, item) {
    //Here I need to push the values
});
```

As you can see I don't have separate arrays for last names and middle names.

I want my output as :

```
[
    { "FIrstName": "Steve", "LastName": "Mark", "MiddleName": "John" },
    { "FIrstName": "James", "LastName": "Andrew", "MiddleName": "wells" },
    { "FIrstName": "Clarke", "LastName": "Finche", "MiddleName": "Gomes" }
]
```

Please assist me.

Comment: It's not clear what the array should look like after processing

Comment: Suggest you fix the source of `names` array. Where does it come from?

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you want to achieve.

```js
var names = ["Steve","Mark","John","James","Andrew", "wells","Clarke","Finche","Gomes"];
var person = [];

for(var i=0; i<names.length; i+=3) {
    person.push({
     FIrstName: names[i],
     LastName: names[i+1],
     MiddleName: names[i+2]
    });
}

document.write(JSON.stringify(person));
```

Also you can firstly split you array to array of chunks..

```js
var names = ["Steve","Mark","John","James","Andrew", "wells","Clarke","Finche","Gomes"];
var chunks = [];

while(names.length) {
 chunks.push(names.splice(0, 3));
}

var result = chunks.map(function(person) {
 return {
     FIrstName: person[0],
     LastName: person[1],
     MiddleName: person[2]
    }
});

document.write(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Comment: Thanks alot. But I want Last Name and Middle Name as well.

Comment: Do you have separate arrays with last names and middle names?

Comment: No, thats my problem.

Comment: @Pearl then you haven't provided a proper problem description in the question. We can't guess what you need or what you have

Answer (score 0):

Use `for` loop with increment `i` by 3

```
var names = ["Steve", "Mark", "John", "James", "Andrew", "wells", "Clarke", "Finche", "Gomes"];

var person = [];

for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i += 3) {
    person.push({
        FIrstName: names[i],
        LastName: names[i + 1],
        MiddleName: names[i + 2]
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could be off-topic, but if you consider using [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs):

```
_.map(_.chunk(names, 3), function (person) {
    return _.zipObject(['FirstName', 'LastName', 'MiddleName'], person);
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/31zhe2ge/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

This is a small proposal with [`Array#reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

```js
var keys = ['FirstName', 'LastName', 'MiddleName'],
    names = ["Steve", "Mark", "John", "James", "Andrew", "wells", "Clarke", "Finche", "Gomes"],
    persons = names.reduce(function (r, a, i) {
        var index = Math.floor(i / 3);
        r[index] = r[index] || {};
        r[index][keys[i % 3]] = a;
        return r;
    }, []);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(persons, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```